# Getting somewhat confused at this point folks

Tags: c#

Am currently looking to use this code to display vehicle information in a data grid view in visual studio 2022 using c# :-

```
connStr = @"Data Source = .\sqlexpress; Initial Catalog = TDsSalesnService; Integrated Security = true";

            // Setting up data adapter for datagridview display
            sqlVehicleDetails = @"SELECT M.MakeName AS Make, ML.ModelName AS Model, V.Registration AS Reg, V.VINNum, V.PriceCost, V.PriceSell, V.Colour, VT.VehicleTypeDesc AS Type, V.Transmission, V.EngineSize, V.FuelType, V.Mileage, V.Condition, V.VehicleYear AS Year, V.Availableness AS Availability
                                  FROM Vehicle V 
                                  JOIN VehicleType VT ON V.VehicleTypeID = VT.VehicleTypeID
                                  JOIN Model ML on V.ModelID = ML.ModelID
                                  JOIN Make M on ML.MakeID = M.MakeID
                                  ORDER BY M.MakeName, ML.ModelName, VT.VehicleTypeDesc, V.VehicleYear ASC";
            conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
            cmdVehicleDetails = new SqlCommand(sqlVehicleDetails, conn); 
            daVehicleDetails = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlVehicleDetails, conn);
            cmdBVehicleDetails = new SqlCommandBuilder(daVehicleDetails);
            daVehicleDetails.FillSchema(dsTDsSalesnService, SchemaType.Source, "Vehicle");
            daVehicleDetails.Fill(dsTDsSalesnService, "Vehicle");
```

This works fine.
The issue comes when I go to write records to the database and it's saying it doesn't accept null values for the first field m.makename.
I was hoping to use and call the vehicle table using this code so i can write new records in the correct format :-

```
        sqlVehicle = @"SELECT * from Vehicle";
        daVehicle = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlVehicle, connStr);
        cmdBVehicle = new SqlCommandBuilder(daVehicle);
        daVehicle.FillSchema(dsTDsSalesnService, SchemaType.Source, "Vehicle");
        daVehicle.Fill(dsTDsSalesnService, "Vehicle");
```

But keeps throwing error about the tables used not being unique.
I truth I would need each line explained as to what is going on so i can map in my head how the process is functioning as I don't think an just understanding it tbh.
Any help would be appreciated.

So the error reads System.ArgumentException:

> 'These columns don't currently have unique values.'

and it points to the `daVehicle.FillSchema(dsTDsSalesnService, SchemaType.Source, "Vehicle");` line.
What am basically trying to do is have the datadgrid view display the vehicle details formatted using the first block of code to make it more legible to the user, but when I go to add records to the database I want to use it's raw format using the second block of code without utilizing the extra naming conventions and there's a extra field there that cause additional problems writing to the db even if i don't use the 2nd block of code.
I can use the second block of code as it for display and writing to the db but it's now useful to the user, looks awful and very hard to reads as it's codes in place of the fields instead of proper names.
[datagridview using 1st block of code only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLnJi.png)
[datagridview using 2nd block of code only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSnho.png)

Comment: What is the exact error message?  What is the exact line of code throwing that error?  What are the relevant runtime values of the variables used on that line of code?

Comment: I don't understand the problem why my question has been closed. I've tried to add extra content in my edit and simply require help in fully understanding the ins and outs of the code snippets.

Comment: It's been a while since I've used these ADO.NET objects (since anyone has, really... This stuff is *ancient*), but it looks like what you're trying to do is add a given table of data to a data set based on a given schema, and the error suggests that the data being added doesn't comply with that schema.  Specifically that the schema requires unique values in a column (probably the primary key) in which the source data does not have unique values.  If the tables and mappings are complex or unwieldy here then you may want to abandon the not-so-strongly-typed ADO.NET data objects.

Comment: Cheers for that, I appreciate the effort of that explanation, that really helped me here.
Many thanks.

Comment: @David I agree that ADO.NET is ancient, but I think it is not bad to learn old stuff first and then new stuff (like Entity Framework) to really understand what is going on.

Comment: @Gerzo-O-B and here you go, it is open now. P.S. allowed myself to improve your formatting.

Comment: Thanks folks for the insight folks, it is appreciated, am currently doing a 2nd year in a foundation degree for software engineering and this is what we're currently being taught and I just don't know the full ins and outs is all. Parts of it are starting to make more sense somewhat and maybe the teaching philosophy is old before new yes. But doing some experimentation and trying to get code to work has lead me down this path and any help is grateful outside of my own findings though these are slim at most.